# I have a question about springboot mapping error

Tags: spring-boot, jsp

I ask for your understanding even if my English is not good.

The jsp files in the WEB-INF/views
It does not work with the mapping intent of the controller.

if i access localhost:8080/index or localhost:8080/welcompage2

No mapping for GET /welcomepage2
No mapping for GET /index

```
@Controller
public class NawaController {

    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String nawaWelcomePage (Model model){

        model.addAttribute("textcode","testcode!");

        return "/index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/welcomepage2",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String nawaWelcomePagetwo (Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("textcode2","testcode2!");

        return "welcomepage2";
    }
```

that's my projact code

My project structure is

src/main/java/Controller/NawaController.java

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/welcomepage
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/welcomepage2

build.gradle

dependencies {

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation('org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper')
    implementation( 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2')
```

}

application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix= /WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix= .jsp
server.servlet.jsp.init-parameters.development=true
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/static/**
```

Nawa2Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Nawa2Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Nawa2Application.class, args);
}

}
```

I'm asking because I don't know what else could be wrong.

Comment: What doesn't work? Please provide more information on what doesn't work, JSP only works in WAR files and with restrictions.

Comment: sorry Deinum i edited my post

Comment: Where is your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated located?

Comment: src/main/java/projactNamefolder/service/Nawa2Application here it is

Comment: Which doesn't cover `controller` package, controller not detected thus 404. Please follow the suggested packaging and put the `@SpringBootApplication` in a top level package which covers all other sub packages.

Comment: oh... thanks Deinum really thank you I learned a lot.